# Why $k\mathbf{v}$ points in the same direction as $(kv_1,kv_2)$

Tags: vectors

I understand everything from the book excerpt below except why it points in the same direction.

[image]

How's the direction here shown? Because it is the original vector simply multiplied by (a positive) scalar?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but the direction of the vectors under scalar multiplication is the same as the vector before the multiplication. To determine the direction of a sum of vectors, you proceed in the same way as you did for individual vectors before addition. For instance, the direction in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be thought of as the slope of the vector. When you find the slope of ${\bf v}$ and $k{\bf v}$, you are essentially multiplying the the numerator and denominator of the slope by $k$. They show in the proof that $\frac{kv_2}{kv_1}=\frac{v_2}{v_1}$.

Comment: so basically scaling the vectors by a scalar |s| (in absolute terms, hence positive)  won't change the direction of the original vectors? This is basically what I was asking, but I get what your saying thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

### $k=0$

$\large k\vec v_1=k\vec v_2=(k.0,k.0)=(0,0)$

---

### $k\ne0$

Slope of line will be $$\large\frac{k\vec v_2}{k\vec v_1}=\frac{\vec v_2}{\vec v_1}$$
same as of vectors.This doesn't mean that it is on same side of origin on the line of this slope or, what you say, $k>0$. It simply means if $k>0$ it'll be on same side of origin on this line and vice-versa for $k<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to think about it. Consider a right triangle with one leg parallel to the $x$-axis having length $v_1 > 0$ and one leg parallel to the $y$-axis having length $v_2 > 0$. The *direction* of the hypotenuse can be found by finding the angle $\theta$ between the hypotenuse and the leg $v_1$, which will be $\theta = \tan^{-1}(v_2/v_1)$. Now, if we scale $v_1$ to $k v_1$ and if we scale $v_2$ to $k v_2$, then the angle $\phi$ between the leg $kv_1$ and the new hypotenuse (after scaling) will be $\phi = \tan^{-1}(kv_2/(kv_1)) = \tan^{-1}(v_2/v_1) = \theta$.

Comment: interesting explanation but makes sense. One more question tangent is normally expressed as tan0=y/x  &  0=tan^-1 (y/x)  am I correct?

Comment: @Tom It would be more easier to understand if you added of figure what you are saying